# Where can I check my MPG video file's resolution?

Tags: video, resolution, mpg

I have an MPG video file. How can I know its resolution?

Comment: Lots of info about your video file with this solution: http://superuser.com/questions/72302/how-do-i-find-out-the-audio-format-of-a-wav-file/72340#72340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows Vista/7 does not show that, try **[MediaInfo Lite](http://www.codecguide.com/download_other.htm#mediainfo)**

Answer (score 2):

Use VLC player

Tools>Media Information>Codec (tab)

Answer (score 1):

right-click on file, properties, then the details tab. Should show the resolution in height and width.

Answer (score 1):

Download, unzip and run **[DPMediaInfo](http://www.paehl.de/cms/dpmedia)**. load your video file and you should see something like this:

[image]

The field **Size** is showing the resolution (160x120 in this case)

*DPMediaInfo is portable, free and open source software.*

Comment: There are 2 size fields :P

Comment: you don't miss much, do you? :)